# delete text from window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a frame showing time/day/date and photos.
the lower frame contain photo and what is next as a text on the right side.
at a certain time, the photo changes and the text changed to a countdown counter. at the  end of the timer the main photo return back and the text showing what is next.
when i run the code I still see the remaining text and I can't destroy it using destroy or grid_forget

```
from tkinter import *
import time



labellist=['y1','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6', ..., 'y9']
lbl=1

root = Tk()


################uper frame for Day---Date----Time#####
frameup = Frame(root, highlightthickness=4, relief='solid', width=0, height=70)
frameup.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2,  padx=5, pady=5)
frameup.config(highlightbackground='red3')

################lower frame############
framelow = Frame(root, highlightthickness=4, relief='solid', width=1, height=250)
framelow.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=180)
framelow.config(highlightbackground='red3')

################frame Left for the photo#############
frameL = Frame(framelow, width=0, height=0, relief='ridge', highlightthickness=1)
frameL.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1)
frameL.config()

###############frame Right for Time Duration Countdown OR Next########
frameR = Frame(framelow)
frameR.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4)
frameR.config(highlightbackground='green')
nexttext = Label(frameR, text=('Next''\n'+(labellist[lbl])), font='infra 45 bold')
nexttext.grid(row=0, column=0)

labelTD = Label(frameup)
labelTD.grid(row=0, column=0)

x1=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x2=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x3=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x4=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x5=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x6=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x7=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x8=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x9=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')
x10=PhotoImage(file='file path.png')

imageList=[x1,x2,x3,x4.....,x10
photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[img])
#
def countdown(n):
    remainingtext = Label(frameR, text=' Time Remaining: ', font='infra 45 bold')
    remainingtext.grid(row=0, column=0)

######this part is to adjust the delay######
    if Hor == 5:
        n = 7080
    if Hor == 6:
        n = 3480

    if n == 1700 or n== 900:
        n= n -10
    if n== 5200 or n==3500:
        n= n -10
######################################

    mn, secs = divmod(n, 60)
    hr, mn = divmod(mn, 60)

    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}")
    labelCD.grid(row=1, column=0)
    labelCD.config(font='infra 55 bold', foreground='black', background='white')

    if n >= 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n - 1)

    else:
        remainingtext.grid_forget()
        #remainingtext.destroy()
########the next 2 line3 is to cover the remaining time with a blank ###########
        # remainingtext = Label(frameR, text='                                       ', font='infra 45 bold')
    
        photo_prog.destroy()
        labelCD.destroy()
        StudioC = Label(frameL, image=photoGenral)
        StudioC.grid(row=0, column=0)
        nexttext = Label(frameR, text=('Next''\n'+(labellist[lbl])), font='infra 45 bold')
        nexttext.grid(row=1, column=0)


########## Showing Day / Date / Time ############
def clock():
    t = time.strftime('%A''\t''%D''\t''%H:%M:%S', time.localtime()).upper()
    global lbl
    if t != '':
        labelTD.config(text=t, font='infra 55 bold', foreground='red3', background='white')
        global Hor
        Hr = time.strftime('%H')
        Mn = time.strftime('%M')
        Sc = time.strftime('%S')
        Dy = time.strftime('%A')
        Hor= int(Hr)
########### next part is the time when i want to photo change
        if int(Hr) == 5 and int(Mn) == 00 and int(Sc) == 0 and (
                Dy == 'Saturday' or 'Sunday'):
            StudioC.destroy()
            ##replace with:## progimage=Label(image=imageList[0])
            ##replace with ##progimage.grid(row=0,column=0)
            countdown(7020)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 4 and int(Mn) == 30 and int(Sc) == 0:  ####just to trigger the timer###
            lbl=1
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()

            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(8800)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr)==7 and int(Mn)==26 and int(Sc)==0:
            lbl=1
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(130)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr)==7 and int(Mn)==56 and int(Sc)==0:
            lbl=1
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(130)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show


        if int(Hr)==8 and int(Mn)==27 and int(Sc)==30:
            lbl = 1
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(130)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr)==8 and int(Mn)==56 and int(Sc)==30:
            lbl=2
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(130)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 12 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:  ####just to trigger the timer###
            lbl=3
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(1680)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 16 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:  ####just to trigger the timer###
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(3540)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 17 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:  ####just to trigger the timer###
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(3540)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 18 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:
            lbl=4
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(1680)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 19 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:
            lbl=5
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(1680)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        if int(Hr) == 22 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:
            lbl=6
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(3540)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show


        if int(Hr) == 23 and int(Mn) == 0 and int(Sc) == 0:
            lbl = 0
            nexttext.destroy()
            StudioC.destroy()
            photo_prog = Label(frameL, image=imageList[1])
            photo_prog.grid(row=0, column=0)
            countdown(1680)  ######## here you can set the duration for each show

        labelTD.after(1000, clock)

labelCD = Label(frameR)
labelCD.grid(row=1, column=0)

StudioC = Label(frameL, image=imageList[10])
StudioC.grid()


clock()
root.geometry('2160x400')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: M8 where are you exactly having the problem in? can you share the "Line of error" in a separate line?

Comment: no error, i want the Time remaining deleted when the countdown end.

Comment: Which Tkinter object do you want to destroy. because after reading your code, there are many objects that are being destroyed.

Comment: @ xpDev, I'm trying to destroy "remainingtext = Label(frameR, text=' Time Remaining: ', font='infra 45 bold')
    remainingtext.grid(row=0, column=0)"
but I still can see that text when the countdown end or n<0 . If you can see in else i used both destroy or grid_forget. I'm still seeing that text

Comment: You created new label `remainingtext` in `countdown()` in each iteration. And so at the end of count down, you delete the last instance, but not the previously created ones.

Comment: @acw1668, You are completely correct.

Comment: Apart from creating `remainingtext` outside `countdown()` function like `labelCD`, you should not destroyed these labels at the end of count down because `countdown()` will be executed more than one in `clock()`.  If you destroy those labels, there will be exception when `countdown()` is executed again.

Answer (score 2):

I added the remaining time text to the LCD and added \n between them it works because it removes the LCD widget properly but not that text.
thanks for your help, nothing seems work maybe something wrong with building the frame,sorry i'm new here and trying to learn, so that was a good walk around :)

Comment: My best tip would be to not `destroy()` the widgets, just call `grid_forget()` to hide and then `grid()` to reveal them.

Comment: I'm using this tip :)

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) said, the `remainingtext` is instantiated every time the `countdown()` function is called. It creates multiple instances of the `remainingtext` and thus, only deletes the one of the top and the other instances are not deleted.

**ANSWER HERE**

I strongly suggest taking out the `remainingtext` and all the other `Tkinter` objects that you want to delete after the `countdown()` function finishes, and typing in outside the `countdown()` function so it is only instantiated once.

```
# making an instance of the remaining text object
remainingtext = Label(frameR, text=' Time Remaining: ', font='infra 45 bold')
remainingtext.grid(row=0, column=0)

def countdown(n):

    # referring it

    global remainingtext

    if Hor == 5:
        n = 7080
    if Hor == 6:
        n = 3480

    if n == 1700 or n== 900:
        n= n -10
    if n== 5200 or n==3500:
        n= n -10
######################################

    mn, secs = divmod(n, 60)
    hr, mn = divmod(mn, 60)

    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}")
    labelCD.grid(row=1, column=0)
    labelCD.config(font='infra 55 bold', foreground='black', background='white')

    if n >= 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n - 1)

    else:
        remainingtext.destroy()

        photo_prog.destroy()
        labelCD.destroy()
        StudioC = Label(frameL)
        StudioC.grid(row=0, column=0)
        nexttext = Label(frameR, text=('Next''\n'+(labellist[lbl])), font='infra 45 bold')
        nexttext.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

I don't have the exact files or anything like that so I cant run the code but I am pretty sure this will work.

(BTW please **organize your code** with "#" and not "###################")

(sorry for my bad spellings.)

Comment: @ xpDev as you can see I have remainingtext. destroy i put # because its not working. even with that line i still can see the word remaining time.
are you sure its working at your side? you can use any 2 or 3 photos to try it

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure this will work. Because the object will be instantiated once and will be destroyed when the `if` statement is not true. As it is being mentioned once outside that loop of a function, the object is instantiated once, and it will be deleted as soon as the `if` statement goes false. I will look into this program with a working project.